# Vaadin 14 executable javascript does not work on IoS

Tags: javascript, ios, vaadin, clipboard

I have developed a Vaadin 14 Flow web app. When pressing a button, the URL should be copied to the clipboard. The javascript is executed because the alert is displayed correctly. On the PC and Android phone the copying works correctly. Unfortunately the code does not work on the Iphone in Safari.

The code comes from here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copy-text-to-clipboard-javascript/

JavaScript:

```
window.copyTextToClipboard = async function copyTextToClipboard(url) {
try {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(url);
    console.log('Content copied to clipboard');
    alert('Copied')
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
    alert('Not Copied')
}}
```

Server-side (Java) that is supposed to call the client-side (Javascript code above):

```
shareUrlButton.addClickListener(event -> {
    String url = "www.test.de";
    UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("copyTextToClipboard($0)",url);
    Notification.show(resourceBundle.getString("shareMessage"),5000, Notification.Position.BOTTOM_CENTER).addThemeVariants(NotificationVariant.LUMO_SUCCESS);
});
```

Comment: So how do you call it?

Comment: I have edited the post and added the code. Sorry :)

Comment: Which Safari iOS version? 13.1 or newer is required. writeText works only in user gesture event.

Comment: My iOS Version is 16.3.1. But can you tell me why it works on the free code camp site?

Comment: It is most likely timing issue, Safari is more strict about determining that event. Have you tried this alternative https://cookbook.vaadin.com/copy-to-clipboard

Comment: Yes, I have already tried. But the button does not work on the Vaadin CookBook page with the Iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short break and a lot of thinking I found the solution to the problem. I write the script directly in the body part of the web page and create a button with an onClick listener on this method. Thanks to all for the help. :)

```
public class MyBootstrapListener implements BootstrapListener {
@Override
public void modifyBootstrapPage(final BootstrapPageResponse response) {
    Document document = response.getDocument();
    Element body = document.body();

    body.append("<script>\n" +
            " async function copyToClipboard(url){\n" +
            "    try {\n" +
            "      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(url);\n" +
            "      console.log('Content copied to clipboard');\n" +
            "  } catch (err) {\n" +
            "      console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            " }"+
            "</script>");
}}
```

Button:

```
shareUrlButton.getElement().setAttribute("onClick","copyToClipboard("+"'https://planyourplaylist.com/playlist/" + playlist.getId().toString()+"')");
```